# Subselect and Max

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Alright, I've been trying to conceptualize this for a better part of the afternoon and still cannot figure out how to structure this subselect.

The data that I need to report are ages for a given student major grouped by the past 3 fiscal years. Each fiscal year has 3 semesters (summer, fall, spring). I need to have my query grouped on the fiscalyear and agerange fields and then count the distinct student id's.

I currently have this for my SQL statement:

```
Select COUNT(distinct StuID), AgeRange, FiscalYear

from tblStatic

where Campus like 'World%' and (enrl_act like 'REG%' or enrl_act like 'SCH%') 
    and StuMaj = 'LAWSC' and FiscalYear IN ('09/10', '10/11', '11/12')

group by FiscalYear, AgeRange

order by FiscalYear, AgeRange
```

So this is all fine and dandy except it doesn't match my headcount of students for the fiscalyear. The reason being, that people may cross over in the age ranges during the fiscal year and is adding them to my count twice.

How can I use a subselect to resolve this duplicate entry? The field I have been trying to get working is my semester field and using a max to find the max semester during a fiscalyear for a given student.

Data Sample:

```
Count   AgeRange            FiscalYear
3           1 to 19             09/10
20          20 to 23            09/10
60          24 to 29            09/10
96          30 to 39            09/10
34          40 to 49            09/10
14          50 to 59            09/10
3           60+                 09/10
2           1 to 19             10/11
24          20 to 23            10/11
73          24 to 29            10/11
109         30 to 39            10/11
43          40 to 49            10/11
11          50 to 59            10/11
2           60+                 10/11
1           1 to 19             11/12
17          20 to 23            11/12
75          24 to 29            11/12
123         30 to 39            11/12
44          40 to 49            11/12
14          50 to 59            11/12
2           60+                 11/12
```

Solution: (Just got this working and produced my headcounts that match what they are suppose to be)

```
Select COUNT(distinct S.StuID), AR.AgeRange, S.FiscalYear
from tblStatic S
INNER JOIN
(   Select S.StuID, MIN(AgeRange) as AgeRange
    From tblStatic S
    Group By S.StuID) AR on S.StuID=AR.StuID

where Campus like 'World%' and (enrl_act like 'REG%' or 
enrl_act like 'SCH%')
and StuMaj = 'LAWSC' and FiscalYear IN ('09/10', '10/11', '11/12') 
group by S.FiscalYear, AR.AgeRange
order by S.FiscalYear, AR.AgeRange
```

Comment: Can you please show sample data and desired results? Instead of storing `AgeRange` (which is subject to change) why not store `Birthdate` (which is not)? Then the calculation can always be dependent on right now or a specific point in time, not relying on whether the `AgeRange` column has been updated in the meantime.

Comment: I can't read that in a comment, sorry. Please edit your question and make sure you can read the data sensibly and that you separate your sample data from desired results.

Comment: Sorry about that, new to the boards. I added my data sample of what I want my end result to look like.

The AgeRange itself is already in my database and is stored for each semester that the student is enrolled. I do have a date of birth field that I messed around with and did get my headcounts to align, but the numbers seemed off because for the previous two years I was having to do a Getdate() -1 or -2 in my datediff expression.

Comment: It's still hard for us to figure out how you got those counts. Can you show the 3 rows in the table (not your desired results) that led to the first row of your desired results, for example? And maybe the 2 row that led to the last row in your desired results? We can't see the semester column or what data is in your table. Imagine if you were trying to write your query without this information.

Comment: Figured it out, I posted my solution at the bottom. Hopefully it helps someone else who might have a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Replace each student's age range with its maximum (or minimum, if you like) age range that fiscal year, *then* count them:

```
;
WITH sourceData AS (
  SELECT
    StudID,
    MaxAgeRangeThisFiscalYear = MAX(AgeRange) OVER
                                (PARTITION BY StudID, FiscalYear),
    FiscalYear
  FROM tblStatic
  WHERE Campus LIKE 'World%'
    AND (enrl_act LIKE 'REG%' OR enrl_act LIKE 'SCH%') 
    AND StuMaj = 'LAWSC'
    AND FiscalYear IN ('09/10', '10/11', '11/12')
)
SELECT
  FiscalYear,
  AgeRange = MaxAgeRangeThisFiscalYear,
  Count    = COUNT(DISTINCT StudID)
FROM sourceData
GROUP BY
  FiscalYear,
  MaxAgeRangeThisFiscalYear
ORDER BY
  FiscalYear,
  MaxAgeRangeThisFiscalYear
```